# How to validate a JWT token

Tags: c#, security, jwt

I'm trying to use JWT tokens. I managed to generate a valid `JWTTokenString` and validated it on the [JWT debugger](https://jwt.io/)  but I'm having an impossible time validating the token in .Net. Here's the code I have so far:

```
class Program {

    static string key = "401b09eab3c013d4ca54922bb802bec8fd5318192b0a75f201d8b3727429090fb337591abd3e44453b954555b7a0812e1081c39b740293f765eae731f5a65ed1";

    static void Main(string[] args) {
        var stringToken = GenerateToken();
        ValidateToken(stringToken);
    }

    private static string GenerateToken() {
        var securityKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(key));

        var credentials = new SigningCredentials(securityKey, SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha256);

        var header = new JwtHeader(credentials);

        var payload = new JwtPayload {
           { "some ", "hello "},
           { "scope", "world"},
        };

        var secToken = new JwtSecurityToken(header, payload);
        var handler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();

        return handler.WriteToken(secToken);

    }

    private static bool ValidateToken(string authToken) {
        var tokenHandler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();
        var validationParameters = GetValidationParameters();

        SecurityToken validatedToken;
        IPrincipal principal = tokenHandler.ValidateToken(authToken, validationParameters, out validatedToken);
        Thread.CurrentPrincipal = principal;
        return true;
    }

    private static TokenValidationParameters GetValidationParameters() {
        return new TokenValidationParameters() {
            //NOT A CLUE WHAT TO PLACE HERE
        };
    }
}
```

All I want is a function that receives a token and returns true or false based on its validity. From research I've seen people use `IssuerSigningToken` to assign the validation key. But when I try to use it, it doesn't seem to exist. Could anyone give me a hand on validating the token?

Answer (score 67, accepted):

You must use the same key to validate the token as the one you use to generate it. Also you need to disable some validations such as expiration, issuer and audiance, because the token you generate doesn't have these information (or you can add these information). Here's a working example:

```
class Program
{
    static string key = "401b09eab3c013d4ca54922bb802bec8fd5318192b0a75f201d8b3727429090fb337591abd3e44453b954555b7a0812e1081c39b740293f765eae731f5a65ed1";

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var stringToken = GenerateToken();
        ValidateToken(stringToken);
    }

    private static string GenerateToken()
    {
        var securityKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(key));
        var credentials = new SigningCredentials(securityKey, SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha256);

        var secToken = new JwtSecurityToken(
            signingCredentials: credentials,
            issuer: "Sample",
            audience: "Sample",
            claims: new[]
            {
                new Claim(JwtRegisteredClaimNames.Sub, "meziantou")
            },
            expires: DateTime.UtcNow.AddDays(1));

        var handler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();
        return handler.WriteToken(secToken);
    }

    private static bool ValidateToken(string authToken)
    {
        var tokenHandler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();
        var validationParameters = GetValidationParameters();

        SecurityToken validatedToken;
        IPrincipal principal = tokenHandler.ValidateToken(authToken, validationParameters, out validatedToken);
        return true;
    }

    private static TokenValidationParameters GetValidationParameters()
    {
        return new TokenValidationParameters()
        {
            ValidateLifetime = false, // Because there is no expiration in the generated token
            ValidateAudience = false, // Because there is no audiance in the generated token
            ValidateIssuer = false,   // Because there is no issuer in the generated token
            ValidIssuer = "Sample",
            ValidAudience = "Sample",
            IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(key)) // The same key as the one that generate the token
        };
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks that's it! I did have to set `ValidateLifetime` and `ValidateIssuer` to `false` though.

Comment: why does `ValidateToken` always return true?

Comment: @CaseyCookston It is a bit odd, but ValidateToken throws an exception if it's not valid.  Therefore, if it gets to that line, it's valid.  Perhaps return void and rename it AssertValidToken(...)?

Comment: I'm trying to implement Apple Sign in, and I get to the point where I get the JWT from Apple, and want to validate it. I've found this post, but there are things I do not understand. In the recommended solution you are building a JWT token yourself to call ValidateToken later on for that token but why not calling ValidateToken on the JWT that gets regturned by Apple.

On the other hand, also on the recommended solution, the variable key is Apple's public key, right?

Comment: If validateToken() always returns true, you don't need to return anything. All you need to do is call validateToken(). You should write Javadocs to clarify that the method throws an exception if the token is invalid.

Comment: try
      {
       IPrincipal principal = tokenHandler.ValidateToken(authToken, validationParameters, out validatedToken);
      }
  catch (Exception e)
 {
       return false;
  }

It's work file

Comment: I noticed that in the validationParameters we have no reference to the algorithm of hashing that we used to generate the credentials of the token, i.e. sha256 in this case (SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha256). Still the validation of the token returns true (i.e., token is valid), independently of the algorithm (I tried others). Why is that?

Answer (score 2):

Validate Token in  Jwt Middleware Class that Invoke Method fire in every request for Authorization

```
JwtMiddleware
    {
        private readonly RequestDelegate _next;
        private readonly TokenValidationParameters _tokenValidationParams;
        public JwtMiddleware(RequestDelegate next, TokenValidationParameters 
        tokenValidationParams)
        {
            _next = next;
            _tokenValidationParams = tokenValidationParams;
        }

    

    public async Task Invoke(HttpContext context)
            {
            try{
                var token = context.Request.Headers["Authorization"].FirstOrDefault()?.Split(" ").Last();
    
                var jwtTokenHandler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();
                // Validation 1 - Validation JWT token format
                var tokenInVerification = jwtTokenHandler.ValidateToken(token, _tokenValidationParams, out var validatedToken);
    
                if (validatedToken is JwtSecurityToken jwtSecurityToken)
                {
                    var result = jwtSecurityToken.Header.Alg.Equals(SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha256, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase);
    
                    if (result == false)
                    {
                        Error Invalid = new Error()
                        {
                            Success = false,
                            Errors = "Token is Invalid"
                        };
    
                        context.Items["Error"] = Invalid;
                    }
                }
           }
           catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Error Invalid = new Error()
                {
                    Success = false,
                    Errors = "Token does not match or may expired."
                };
                context.Items["Error"] = Invalid ; // userService.GetById(userId);
            }
                await _next(context);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

In my case I only want to validate if the signature is correct. Most likely you will probably want to use @meziantou answer. But if you only want to verify that the message has not been tampered with here is an example. Lastly since I am the only person generating this tokens and I know I will be generating them using HmacSha256 I am using this approach.

```
using Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens;
using System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt;
using System.Security.Claims;
using System.Security.Cryptography;
using System.Text;

class Program
{
    static readonly byte[] key = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("f645b33ef0d04cbe859777ac6f46226d");

    // use this algorithm for example to work
    static readonly string securityAlgorithm = SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha256;

    static void Main()
    {
        var token = GenerateToken();
        var isTokenValid = IsJwtTokenValid(token);
        if (isTokenValid)
            Console.WriteLine(true);
    }

    /// <summary>
    ///     This method assumes token has been hashed using HMACSHA256 algorithm!
    /// </summary>
    private static bool IsJwtTokenValid(string token)
    {
        // example of token:
        //                  header                              payload                                      signature
        // eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJzdWIiOiJmb29AZ21haWwuY29tIiwiZXhwIjoxNjQ1NzM1MDU2fQ.Gtrm2G_35ynyNd1-CjZ1HsvvFFItEsXPvwhaOsN81HQ

        // from JWT spec
        static string Base64UrlEncode(byte[] input)
        {
            var output = Convert.ToBase64String(input);
            output = output.Split('=')[0]; // Remove any trailing '='s
            output = output.Replace('+', '-'); // 62nd char of encoding
            output = output.Replace('/', '_'); // 63rd char of encoding
            return output;
        }

        try
        {
            // position of second period in order to split header+payload and signature
            int index = token.IndexOf('.', token.IndexOf('.') + 1);

            // Example: Gtrm2G_35ynyNd1-CjZ1HsvvFFItEsXPvwhaOsN81HQ
            string signature = token[(index + 1)..];

            // Bytes of header + payload
            // In other words bytes of: eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJzdWIiOiJmb29AZ21haWwuY29tIiwiZXhwIjoxNjQ1NzM1MDU2fQ
            byte[] bytesToSign = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(token[..index]);

            // compute hash
            var hash = new HMACSHA256(key).ComputeHash(bytesToSign);
            var computedSignature = Base64UrlEncode(hash);

            // make sure that signatures match
            return computedSignature.Length == signature.Length 
                && computedSignature.SequenceEqual(signature);
        }
        catch
        {
            return false;
        }
    }

    private static string GenerateToken()
    {
        var securityKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(key);
        var credentials = new SigningCredentials(securityKey, securityAlgorithm);

        var secToken = new JwtSecurityToken(
            signingCredentials: credentials,
            claims: new[]
            {
                new Claim(JwtRegisteredClaimNames.Sub, "foo@gmail.com")
            },
            expires: DateTime.UtcNow.AddDays(1));

        var handler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();
        return handler.WriteToken(secToken);
    }
    
}
```

Comment: That did the trick for me, with Salesforce Custom Activity JWT tokens. Leaving the comment for anyone trying to figure out how to get through the JWT implementation on SMC

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following code to validate a JWT Token in C#. In my config, I determined expired time as *3 days* and I'm checking *issuer* and *audience*.

```
    var issuer; // The same issuer as the one that generate the token
    var audience; // The same audience as the one that generate the token
    var key; // The same key as the one that generate the token  

    public bool TokenKontrol(string authToken)
    {
        try
        {
            var tokenHandler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();
            var validationParameters = GetValidationParameters();

            SecurityToken validatedToken;
            IPrincipal principal = tokenHandler.ValidateToken(authToken, validationParameters, out validatedToken);
            
            if (principal.Identity != null && principal.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
            {
                return true;
            }
            else
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return false;

        }
    }

    private TokenValidationParameters GetValidationParameters()
    {
      return new TokenValidationParameters()
        {
            ValidateLifetime = true,
            ValidateAudience = true,
            ValidateIssuer = true,
            ValidIssuer = issuer,
            ValidAudience = audience,
            IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(key))
        };
    }
```

Comment: Could you please also provide the token generation code? Since validating `Issuer` depends on how the token is generated in first place.