# using async/await - c#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api

I have the following code. What exactly does the code do? Why do we need the `Stopwatch`, `XmlSerializer`, `MemoryStream`. Is there are simpler way of doing it using `async/await`?
Also does using `contentResponse.Result;` lead to a deadlock situation always.

```
    public T GetResponse<T>()
    {
        var response = default(T);

            using (HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient())
            {
                httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Authorization", authHeader);

                Stopwatch watch = Stopwatch.StartNew();

                var contentResponse = httpClient.GetAsync(uri.ToString());

                try
                {
                    contentResponse.Wait();
                }
                catch (Exception exception)
                {

                }

                var wsResponseContent = contentResponse.Result;
                wsResponseContent.Content.LoadIntoBufferAsync();
                var resultTask = wsResponseContent.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                resultTask.Wait();

                string wsResponseContentText = resultTask.Result;

                if (watch.IsRunning)
                    watch.Stop();

                wsResponseContent.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
                if (wsResponseContent.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                {
                    XmlSerializer result = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T));

                    using (MemoryStream sresultStream = new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(wsResponseContentText)))
                    {
                        response = (T)result.Deserialize(sresultStream);
                        sresultStream.Close();
                    }
                }
            }
       
        return response;
    }
```

Comment: That code is terrible in so many ways that it'd take a long time to answer. Start by reading: https://stackoverflow.com/a/69859015/2141621

Comment: As for the Stopwatch - I don't see it being used anywhere, so it's almost the same as if it wasn't there - except it adds complexity.

Comment: Well, the stop watch does get created, started and stopped. All useful operations, _if you are going to eventually read its value_ (unlike here, where it's ignored). Get rid of it

Comment: @Flydog57 you mean read stopwatch values? is it used to track the total response time? has it got anything to with parallel processing?

Comment: @JonasH Absolutely no way, "What exactly does the code do?" Code Review doesn't explain code.

Comment: Normally a Stopwatch is used in two ways, either to benchmark an operation ("how long does this take" - in which case, it gets removed before before promotion to production) or logging (again how long did this take). In this case `watch` is scoped within the `using` block. It gets created, started and stopped, but never read. It has **_nothing_** to do with parallel processing. It's only purpose here is to measure the elapsed Time between `StartNew` and `Stop`

Comment: @Flydog57 does using `.Result` lead to a deadlock? should i be using `async/await` to read the content?

Comment: I'm assuming you found some sample code somewhere and you are hoping that you can copy/paste it into a solution to your problem. Blindly copy/pasting crappy code results in two copies of crsppy code (doubling down on the _techincal debt_). When you find something on the internet, take the time to understand it. Step through it in a debugger. See how it can be adapted to your needs and improved. If you ship this code, folks are going to be staring at it saying "That Stopwatch doesn't do anything, I wonder if I'll break something if I remove it" for the next N years (really)

Comment: The code is legacy code, I am not even sure what does `T` stand for

Comment: there should be a more readable/understandable alternative, hence posted the question

Comment: Does `.Result` Result in deadlock? It can: https://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html . When writing modern async code, use `await` and make everything `async`, _all the way down_

Comment: The `try { contentResponse.Wait(); } catch (Exception exception) { }` is awful. Just remove this exception handling.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need for the StopWatch in this code. Usually used as a diagnostic tool, it can be useful. But not in this instance.
From the code below it seems that it reads a string send over the web and tries to read it as an XML format. Thus the need for the `MemoryStream` and `XMLSerializer`.

As for your deadlock situation. It is always because two instances is trying to access the same instance. You can avoid this by await your functions properyly.
If oyu really want a proper `async` implement the function as follow:

```
public async Task<T> GetResponse<T>()
{
    var response = default(T);

    using (HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient())
    {
        httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Authorization", authHeader);

        var contentResponse = await httpClient.GetAsync(uri.ToString());

        await wsResponseContent.Content.LoadIntoBufferAsync();
        var wsResponseContentText = await wsResponseContent.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

        wsResponseContent.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
        
        if (wsResponseContent.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            XmlSerializer result = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T));

            using (MemoryStream sresultStream = new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(wsResponseContentText)))
            {
                response = (T)result.Deserialize(sresultStream);
                sresultStream.Close();
             }
        }
    }
   
    return response;
}
```

In the above code if a function has `async` in it. We can await the result instead of the task. For example in the code below:

```
public async Task<int> GetNumber5Async() {
    return 5;
}
```

If we are to call it like you did before:

```
var number5 = GetNumber5Async(); // Returns Task<int>
```

We will receive back a Task we will need to get the results from. However, if we immediately await the Task:

```
var number5 = await GetNumber5Async(); // Returns 5
```

We immedaitely get the result back and don't have to do `number5.Wait(); number5.result;`

---

### Turtles all the way Down

One thing you will need know when working with Async Methods is the concept of 'Turtes all the way Down'.
Simply what it says is if you have a async method anywhere, all your methods call it and calling those methods needs to be async as well.
So what is needed for a method to be async?

1. In requires to be a `Task`. So instead of returning a value, it will need to return a `Task` with a value encapsulated.

For example:

```
// None Async
public int GetNumber5() { return 5;} 

// Async
public async Task<int> GetNumber5Async() { return 5; }
```

2. Requires the `async` descriptor to both use and call o be able to `await` a function.

For example:

```
// None Async
void GetANumber(){
    var num5 = GetNumber5();
}

// Async
async void GetANumber(){
    var num5 = await GetNumber5Async();
}
```

---

### Avoiding Deadlocks with Async

Usually awaiting a function is engough. But if it still creates deadlocks you can add '.ConfigureAwait(false);'

For Example:

```
var num5 = await GetNumber5Async().ConfigureAwait(false);
```

Comment: Ah, someone else who uses "Turtles all the way Down" to describe async/await coding

Comment: Stephen Cleary's rough rule: _if you are writing library code, use `ConfigureAwait(false)`, if you're not, don't_ has worked for me so far