# JWT with ASP.NET Core MVC application

Tags: asp.net-core, jwt, asp.net-core-mvc

[I created a service](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NfKJ1.png)

[I have implemented my method that will generate a token](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hfH9O.png)

[At my Action Login I don’t know how to ensure the comsommation of the generated token on everything I use (Razor, HTML)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/InE8a.png)

I would like to set up an Authentication using JWT token with an ASP.NET Core MVC application.

This is the first time using a token, all the articles and tutorials that I had to consult use JWT with the Web API which is not my case, because my project is of type MVC.

Can someone help me or orient me?

Comment: can you add some code? examples of what have you tried till now.

Comment: I added my code you can check see

Comment: @AddaIssaAbdoulRazak Welcome to Stack Overflow.
Please take the [tour] to learn how Stack Overflow works and read [ask] on how to improve the quality of your question.
Then [edit] your question to include your source code as a working [mcve], which can be compiled and tested by others.
[Please do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: I think you misunderstand the useful of JWT, In your login method, You need to verify whether the user's account password is correct, and then generate the corresponding JWT token, and then you only need to use this token to access the protected endpoint without entering the account password multiple times.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are trying to do is Authenticate the user by `JWT` which is not possible. You'll have to generate `JWT` after the user has logged in with a username and password.

Return this token as a response to the user so the user can use the token for other API requests.

[For validation refere this.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50204844/how-to-validate-a-jwt-token)

> When should you use JSON Web Tokens?

> **Authorization**: This is the most common scenario for using JWT. Once the user is logged in, each subsequent request will include the JWT, allowing the user to access routes, services, and resources that are permitted with that token. Single Sign On is a feature that widely uses JWT nowadays, because of its small overhead and its ability to be easily used across different domains.

> **Information Exchange**: JSON Web Tokens are a good way of securely transmitting information between parties. Because JWTs can be signed—for example, using public/private key pairs—you can be sure the senders are who they say they are. Additionally, as the signature is calculated using the header and the payload, you can also verify that the content hasn't been tampered with.